# Write a Program to declare a double variable doubleVal and initialize it with the value of 2^16. and convert to short

Tags: java

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Double doubleVal = Math.pow(2,16);
    Short shortVal = (Short) doubleVal;
     System.out.println(shortVal);
  }
}
```

whats wrong in this code

Comment: What’s the problem?

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem. What is indicating to you that this code is 'wrong'? Are there any error messages you are getting? Please edit this into the question.

Comment: *whats wrong in this code*  is off-Topic. Please tell us what your Problem is

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast a `Double` to `Short`.

`Double` and `Short` both inherit from `Number`, but they are not related (`Double` is not a superclass of `Short`)

Your best solution is to use primitives:

```
double doubleVal = Math.pow(2,16);
short shortVal = (short) doubleVal;
```

If you need to use the wrapper types, then you still need to convert through primitives:

```
Double doubleVal = Math.pow(2,16);
Short shortVal = doubleVal.shortValue();
```